# MP3 files reduce in size and get corrupted after uploading from a form

Tags: php, file-upload, corruption

Here's the original mp3 file: [Pon-3jay LongR.mp3](http://eqreverb.com/sound_manager/songs/Pon-3jay%20LongR.mp3)
And here's the corrupted version: [pon-3jay longr.mp3](http://eqreverb.com/form/uploads/songs/djdavid98/pon-3jay%20longr.mp3)

This is the script that moves the files over:

```
<?php

require_once "File.php";
$path = "uploads/songs/";
$valid_formats = array("mp3");
$File = new File();

$path = $path."djdavid98/";

    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $name = $_FILES['song']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['song']['size'];
        $tmp  = $_FILES['song']['tmp_name'];

        if (!is_dir($path)) mkdir($path, 0777, true);

        if($File->upload($tmp, $actual_song_name,$path)){
            echo response($path.$actual_song_name,$actual_song_name,$txt.".".$ext);
        }
        else echo errText("Upload failed!", $path );
    }

function errText($str,$fileName){
    return '{"song":{"sucess":"0","message":"' .$str. '","fileName":"' . $fileName . '"}}';
}
function response($filePath,$actualFileName,$fileName){
    return '{"song":{"sucess":"1","path":"' . $filePath . '","fileName":"' . $fileName . '"}}';
}

?>
```

File.php:

```
<?php
    class File {
        public function upload($file, $filename, $target_path) {
            if (empty($filename)) { break; }
            try {
                $target_path = $target_path . $filename;

                if(move_uploaded_file($file, $target_path)) {
                    return true;
                } else{
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                echo "Error on <strong>Line " . $ex->getLine() . " </strong>: " . $ex->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Form:

```
<form class="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="height:0;opacity:0;">
    <div class="grid-100 grid-parent">
        <div class="grid-20">
            ...
            <div data-input>
                <span>Song</span>
                <div class="grid-100 grid-parent fileSelect">
                    <div class="grid-60">
                        <input type="text" disabled class="file-holder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-wrapper grid-40">
                        <input type="file" name="song" required>
                        <div class="button styleWarning">Browse</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-80 grid-parent">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This script is run on a CloudFlare host, just in case that changes anything. From what I noticed, all of the uploaded mp3 files upload as the same exact file. I honestly have no idea why this happens and how I could fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the same thing happen to non mp3 files?

Comment: @Gavin The script also uploads image files, which get uploaded just fine.

Comment: Is there anything else happening behind the scenes, such as an ftp transfer?

Comment: @Gavin This is all the script. The only ftp transfers I use is uploading the scripts.

Comment: Do you have root access to the server/host?  I wonder if the file is corrupt before move_uploaded_file is called?  other options could be a malfunctioning network device / proxy,  to test that try from a different location or local to the server (if you are not already).  I suppose it also possible that this is a service running on the host that could alter mp3 files, to test that try your code local to your machine,  or at a different host.  Incidentaly,  your code looks fine to me.

Comment: @Gavin I do have an apache server set up locally as well, same problem happens.

Comment: @Gavin From what I noticed, all of the uploaded mp3 files upload as the same exact file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28839/discussion-between-djdavid98-and-gavin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cover art (image) file is inadvertently saved instead of the mp3 file.

ref the following lines in ajaxprocessform.php:

```
$tmp = $_FILES['cover']['tmp_name']; //this is the image

if (!is_dir($path)) mkdir($path, 0777, true); 

if($File->upload($tmp, $actual_song_name,$path)){ //image saved with mp3 path
```